# unix sed command matching a word

Tags: linux, unix, sed

I am trying to match a line and use sed command to substitute it. Some thing like

```
aaa = 10
 aaa =10
aaa=10
```

My sed regular expression should match all those patterns and should replace with something like bbb=5. I tried with

```
     sed -i '/ *aaa *= */bbb=5'
```

But this is not properly working for all the patterns. Any help will be really appreciable.

Comment: Should be `sed -i '/ *aaa *=.*/bbb=5/'`

Comment: The first step to this sort of problem is to accurately specify the problem.  The solution will follow almost immediately.  (Given the current problem specification, it would seem that replacing all input lines with `bbb=5` is an acceptable solution.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 sed -i 's/\s*aaa\s*=\s*[0-9]*/bbb=5/' input_file
```

Answer (score 4):

```
cat a | sed -e '1s/aaa =10/bbb=10/' -e '2s/ aaa =10/bbb=10/' -e '3s/aaa=10/bbb=10/'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cat myfile | sed 's/\s*aaa\s*=\s*\(.*\)/bbb = \1/'
```

The \s character class matches both tab and space

Comment: \1 requires sed option -r on some distros